# Can germs exist at endpoints of functions?

Tags: general-topology

If $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ for all $x\leq0$, and undefined elsewhere, would $f$ and $g$ define the same germ at $x=0$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A germ at $a$ is an element of the stalk at $a$, and a stalk is a limit of spaces of functions defined on open neighbourhoods $U\ni a$. Thus your setup makes sense only if $0$ is not only an endpoint of where the functions are defined, but in fact of the topological space of interest itself, i.e., we consider perhaps $X=(-\infty,0]$, not $X=\Bbb R$. But then, yes, certainly two functions that are defined and agree on some open neighbourhood $(-\epsilon,0]$ of $0$, define the same germ.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.